# How can I prevent my blur event form over ridding my click event?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a menu which I want to display when the input is focused, so I used the focus and blur event of the input to trigger the function that either shows or hide the menu.

The problem is when I want to add events inside the menu (for example a click event), the blur event of the input is always triggered first so the click event of the menu is never triggered

Here's a sample code to illustrate my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/f7xvg1L9/27/

```js
function hide () {
  document.getElementById('box').style.display = 'none';
}

function show () {
  document.getElementById('box').style.display = 'block';
}

function select () {
  document.getElementById('select').innerHTML = 'selected';
}

document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('blur', hide)
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('focus', show)
document.getElementById('box').addEventListener('click', select)
```

```css
#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='input'/>
<div id='box'>Test</div>
<p id='select'></p>
```

(the select() function is never called)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can do a lot of things in CSS instead of Javascript for this.

Here, setup a CSS rule for the selector `input:focus + #box, #box:active`, which displays the `box`.

`#box:active` is there to register the click on the box before it disappears, it won't work without it.

```js
document.getElementById('box').addEventListener('click',() => {
  document.getElementById('select').innerHTML = 'selected';
});
```

```css
#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
}

input:focus + #box, #box:active{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='input'/>
<div id='box'>
  Test
</div>
<p id='select'></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's an unfortunate side effect.
But it can be solved quite easily by using different events.

Instead of using a focus/blur handler, you can just use click events for all 3 of these, since focussing the input is the same as clicking inside it. And Blurring the input is the same as clicking outside of the input.

So if we show the box onclick of the input, we can then add a different click event to the rest of the document. Inside that click event, we can check if the current click is inside the box or not and act accordingly.

```js
var box = document.getElementById('box');
var input = document.getElementById('input');

var change_text = function() {
  box.innerHTML = 'selected';
};
var outside_click = function( event ) {
  if ( !box.contains(event.target) ) {
    box.style.display = 'none';
    document.removeEventListener('click', outside_click);
  }
};
var show_box = function( event ) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  box.style.display = 'block';
  document.addEventListener('click', outside_click);
};
box.addEventListener('click', change_text);
input.addEventListener('click', show_box);
```

```css
#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='input'/>
<div id='box'>Test</div>
```

Edit: But the CSS solution posted above is a way better and easier solution.

Answer (score 0):

Two things you can use:

- [event.relatedTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FocusEvent/relatedTarget) - This is only valid for `focus` and `blur` events on only contains a value if the `relatedTarget` has `tabindex=1` or greater.
- the [`useCapture` phase of `addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) which allows you to get at events before most things get to them.

In the example below I use them both, though I really only needed to use the `event.relatedTarget` since that let me see that the user was clicking on the `#box` and prevent from closing the box.

```js
function hide (evt) {
  if (evt.relatedTarget && evt.relatedTarget.id === 'box') {
    document.getElementById('box').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('input').focus();
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById('box').style.display = 'none';
  }
}

function show (evt) {
  document.getElementById('box').style.display = 'block';
}

function select (evt) {
  document.getElementById('select').innerHTML = 'selected';
}

document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('blur', hide);
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('focus', show);
document.getElementById('box').addEventListener('click', select, true);
```

```css
#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input"/>
<div id="box" tabindex="1">
  Test
</div>
<p id="select"></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the most quick and simple way would be to use `setTimeout` in the `hide` function.

```js
function hide () {
  setTimeout(function(){
      document.getElementById('box').style.display = 'none';
  }, 300)
}

function show () {
  document.getElementById('box').style.display = 'block';
}

function select () {
  document.getElementById('select').innerHTML = 'selected';
}

document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('blur', hide)
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('focus', show)
document.getElementById('box').addEventListener('click', select)
```

```css
#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='input'/>
<div id='box'>Test</div>
<p id='select'></p>
```

Comment: this is going to lead to an arms race of race conditions